# Accessing public calendar from firefox after upgrade to Exchange 2007

Tags: exchange-2007, firefox, thunderbird

Our company email/calendar server is in Exchange.  I work on Linux using Firefox/Thunderbird.

We have an office calendar as a shared "Public Folder", and in the past I've successfully accessed this using firefox.  We've now upgraded to Exchange 2007.  When I try to log in, the "WebAccess Light" check box is explicitly enabled, with the following text:

> The Light client provides fewer features and is sometimes faster. Use the Light client if you are on a slow connection or using a computer with unusually strict browser security settings. If you are using a browser **other than Internet Explorer** 6 or later, you can only use the Light client.

[Aside - is this not anti-competitive behaviour?]

Using the [Lightning Plugin](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/lightning/) + [Exchange Data Provider](http://gitorious.org/lightning-exchange-provider/pages/Home) for thunderbird, I can access and modify my personal Exchange calendar but I am unable to access/modify the public calendar in either Thunderbird or Firefox.

1. Is it possible to access an Exchange "Public Folder/Shared Calendar" from Thunderbird?  If so, how?
2. Is it possible to access said calendar from firefox?

I will be restricted regarding what changes I can have made on the Server side.  For example, moving the calendar or having it published for all to see on the web would probably not be acceptable.

One final point, my main requirement is to be able to add/remove my own items in the calendar.  With this in mind, is it possible to have Exchange sync from my personal calendar to the shared calendar?

---

**UPDATE:**
Apologies to anybody who saw this as Exchange 2010 - I've just been corrected that we've updated to 2007!

Comment: Apparently this has been addressed in 2010, unfortunately this is not an option for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to public folders hosted on Exchange 2007 is not possible with the Light version of OWA. Speaking as a Firefox user on an Exchange 2007 system, I feel your pain. As has been pointed out, this has been fixed in 2010 but that doesn't help either of us yet.